# Specific dynamic field not indexed in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have the following definition in my SOLR schema:

```
<dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
```

In most documents where I have dynamic fields with the suffix '_s' it is indexed fine, i.e.

```
{
    "id": "http://rdf.abbvienet.com/data/tripReport/interaction/a114fa3a-a2ef-4c31-aa0d-0fd1825f9f54",
    "name": "BTK Inhibitor",
    "type": "http://schemas.abbvienet.com/ontologies/data.owl#TripReportInteraction",
    "source": "urn:x-abbvie:trakm",
    "meeting_name_s": "CHI Conference - Drug Discovery Chemistry",
    "location_s": "San Diego, CA",
    "title_s": "BTK Inhibitor",
    "alternate_title_s": "BTK Inhibitor",
    "company_s": "Pharmacyclics",
    "date_t": "2013-04-16T05:00:00Z",
    "category_s": "New Competitor,Competition,AbbVie Target",
    "related_diseases_s": "Autoimmune - Lupus,Autoimmune - Rheumatoid Arthritis",
    "related_protein_types_s": "Protein kinase",
    "related_mechanisms_of_action_s": "Immunomodulator"
  }
```

This works fine where if in the query I use 'title_s:*', that returns all the fields with the title field.  However, I have this other set of documents like the one below:

```
{
    "type": "http://schemas.abbvienet.com/ontologies/data.owl#Target",
    "source": "urn:x-abbvie:targets",
    "id": "http://rdf.abbvienet.com/data/target/BTK",
    "name": "BTK",
    "common_name_s": "Bruton agammaglobulinemia tyrosine kinase",
    "description_w": "The protein encoded by this gene plays a crucial role in B-cell development. Mutations in this gene cause X-linked agammaglobulinemia type 1, which is an immunodeficiency characterized by the failure to produce mature B lymphocytes, and associated with a failure of Ig heavy chain rearrangement. Alternative splicing results in multiple transcript variants encoding different isoforms. [provided by RefSeq, Dec 2013]",
    "alias": [
      "XLA",
      "PSCTK1",
      "ATK",
      "truncated Bruton agammaglobulinemia tyrosine kinase",
      "agammaglobulinaemia tyrosine kinase",
      "tyrosine-protein kinase BTK",
      "dominant-negative kinase-deficient Brutons tyrosine kinase",
      "tyrosine-protein kinase BTK isoform (lacking exon 14)",
      "B-cell progenitor kinase"
    ]
  }
```

A solr query of 'common_name_s:*' returns nothing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Field Definitions:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="name" type="exact_no_case" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="name_edge" type="exact_no_case_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="name_partial" type="word_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<copyField source="name" dest="name_edge" />
<copyField source="name" dest="name_partial" />
<copyField source="name" dest="by_words" />
<copyField source="name" dest="by_words_edge" />
<copyField source="name" dest="by_phonetics" />
<field name="alias" type="exact_no_case" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="alias_edge" type="exact_no_case_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="alias_partial" type="word_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="alias" dest="alias_edge" />
<copyField source="alias" dest="alias_partial" />
<copyField source="alias" dest="by_words" />
<copyField source="alias" dest="by_words_edge" />
<copyField source="alias" dest="by_phonetics" />
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="by_words" type="word_match" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="by_partial_words" type="word_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false"  multiValued="true" />
<field name="by_words_edge" type="word_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="by_phonetics" type="phonetic_match" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_w" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_d" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_f" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_l" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<copyField source="*_s" dest="by_words" />
<copyField source="*_s" dest="by_partial_words" />
<copyField source="*_s" dest="by_words_edge" />
<copyField source="*_s" dest="by_phonetics" />
<copyField source="*_w" dest="by_words" />
```

Comment: Using the Schema Brwoser in the SOLR Admin tool, I can see that only for this common_name_s field, there is no index. All other _s dynamic fields have an index. Does anyone know why, or how I can re-enable the index?

Comment: That's a interesting problem. A couple of things you can do:  1) Can u verify if the second document "id": "http://rdf.abbvienet.com/data/target/BTK" is indeed indexed? 2) Can u verify what is the field type of your "id" field in the schema? 3) If you can index only this one document, you can check logs and see if its throwing an error while indexing this particular doc.

Comment: If I search bu the 'id:"http://rdf.abbvienet.com/data/target/BTK"', it comes back find.. essentially though for all these documents common_name_s and description_w are not indexed... alias and all other fields are. I'll trying manually adding a document of this type and see if I get any errors.

Comment: Also, it is all documents that were added with the common_name_s/description_w fields.. of course all these docs are from the same source.. so there could be something going on there.

Comment: Could you post all of your fields definitions ? Maybe another one is taking priority over your dynamicField for "common_name_s"

Comment: I updated the post to include all of my field definitions.